# installing lubuntu with 512MB RAM

Tags: system-installation

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my desktop, with 512MB RAM so I downloaded xubuntu. but I couldn't install it. I got the same error while downloading and installing lubuntu. I came across md5sums. but I cannot actually check my md5sum. I have done a lot of reading , but there was nothing in the layman terms. I can`t run a check on the file.
I need help in installing any of the variants of Ubuntu compatible on my system.

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: Might help us to know what error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

What OS is on the machine you are trying to check the md5sum with ?

If it is a windows machine then try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows

If a linux machine - navigate to where the iso is and

```
md5sum "iso.name"
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Linux

You can find the md5sum hash here - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes